# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I am following the Tensorflow tutorial on how to create a dataset from a pd dataframe. But I'm getting this error:

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).

The notebook to reproduce this can be found here:

https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jenyckee/478fe091b34b043154db03a802d40673/pandas_dataframe.ipynb#scrollTo=bB9C0XJkyQEk

I'm not providing a NumPy array so why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

A pandas dataframe is a usually a numpy array decorated with a column and an index.

To access that numpy array, you can just use `df.values` where `df` is your dataframe.

I would guess from the error message that TensorFlow does not want ints as a base type. So I would first try to cast the dataframe to doubles, e.g. with

```
df = df.astype(float)
```

and then pass it to your function.